# Builtin map methods reference

Tags: dictionary, go, methods, interface

Please help to find the list of builtin map type method. Sources are OK. I see `Add` and `Set` in different examples and I would like to know the difference.

The following was found but gives no help:

https://golang.org/src/runtime/hashmap.go - implementation, but where is the interface?
https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action - an article on maps, but can't find the complete method list.

Comment: "the list of builtin map type method" What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: go-maps-in-action provide all the relative information for methods. Other things depends on requirements. What are your requirements of using maps. You should implement the maps and then ask if something you wants to know about maps.

Answer (score 2):

Map types in Go do not implement any interfaces (except the empty interface `interface{}`) because map types have no methods.

To verify:

```
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(map[int]int{}).NumMethod())
```

Which prints (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HWvrTA4wZnV)):

```
0
```

Setting / getting / removing elements from a map is covered by the language spec (e.g. [Index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions)). Also the number of entries in a map is a builtin function: [`len()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len).